# Change mouse cursor as my own image

Tags: html, css

I have to change my mouse pointer of my own image for home page contain background images. i tried in local with this code

```
<a href="abc.html" style="cursor:url(kora.cur)">image</a>
```

But it doesnt change .. help on the same

Comment: you cannot access the mouse-curser via php. or what do you mean?

Comment: In what browsers does it work/not work? Does the cur file exist, are you 100% sure?

Comment: **Might** help: http://beradrian.wordpress.com/2008/01/08/cross-browser-custom-css-cursors/

Comment: @bazmegakapa Good source for information, but also thanks for my new poster

Answer (score -2):

You're missing the quotation marks around the location of the image and the semicolon to terminate the style, this should work for you, if not then reply if it doesn't

```
<a href="abc.html" style="cursor:url('kora.cur');">image</a>
```

Comment: Yes its working.. i changed code like
<A HREF="javascript:doLink();" onMouseOver="status=url[ct];return true;" 
onMouseOut="status=''" style="cursor: url(icon.cur),default;">
 <IMG NAME="Ad_Image" SRC="sites/default/files/logo1.jpg" BORDER=0 width="1350" height="615" style="margin:0;padding:0;">
</A>

it was not working on internet explorer.. But working fine in Firefox and chrome

Comment: This answer is not correct. In `url()` quoting is optional, just like the final semicolon in a set of CSS rules.

Comment: Also, you should always specify a standard fallback option at the end.

Comment: can u tell me the cursor is not working in IE . but working fine in firefox n crome.. please resolve this issue

Comment: @Ashlash: see the link posted by bazmegakapa in the comments to your question. You need to specify the URL relative to the base document and not the style sheet for IE